# Preferred way to pep8 this line of code

Tags: python, pep8

I'm a bit new to forcing python code to be PEP8, what is the preferred way to PEP8 this line of code:

```
emissionprob = preprocessing.normalize(self.random_state.rand(self.n_components, self.n_symbols), norm='l1', axis=1, copy=False)
```

personally I'm a bit weird and like it this way, is this considered PEP8?

```
emissionprob = preprocessing.normalize(
    self.random_state.rand(
        self.n_components, 
        self.n_symbols
    ), 
    norm='l1', 
    axis=1, 
    copy=False
)
```

Comment: yes that's fine... This is really just a matter of personal style

Comment: PEP8 is a style _guide,_ not a style demand. If you follow the guidelines, your code is likely to look better but remember that one of the first guidelines in PEP8 is to ignore it if it damages readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same preference as you do and the pep8 validator doesn't think it's wrong: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8

Usually I think it's recommended  to do it like this however, I find it less readable:

```
emissionprob = preprocessing.normalize(self.random_state.rand(self.n_components, 
                                                              self.n_symbols), 
                                       norm='l1', 
                                       axis=1, 
                                       copy=False)
```

I personally do it like this (note the trailing comma's everywhere):

```
emissionprob = preprocessing.normalize(
    self.random_state.rand(
        self.n_components, 
        self.n_symbols,
    ), 
    norm='l1', 
    axis=1, 
    copy=False,
)
```

Comment: sweet, but most of the code looks like your last 'less readable', should I walk my own path and expand it all or should I keep it consistent?
Additionally the line is 97, how does one solve that?

Comment: nice with the trailing comma's, I knew it was possible but considered ugly except for lists

Comment: I don't want to be that guy but, isn't the first 80char ?

Comment: it could very well be 80 char, I wrote it in the stackoverflow editor and didn't check the line length.

Comment: Personally I think code styles are very personal and you should just do whatever feels good to you, but do note that it's a good thing to keep it consistent within a project. No matter how bad a code style is, an inconsistent code style is worse.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just post how I would do it, I think this looks cleaner but as I said before once you obey the basics of PEP-8, the rest is just a matter of personal style:

```
emissionprob = preprocessing.normalize(
    self.random_state.rand(self.n_components, self.n_symbols),
    norm='l1',
    axis=1,
    copy=False)
```

IMHO you are using way too many extra lines, it just seems like you are going overboard with it.

Comment: I think this one looks better since it gives you the one-arg-per-line without breaking the line size guideline.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are doing it is fine, but I would try to keep it consistent with the existing code.

In this special case, I would probably assign the first argument to a temporary variable.

```
rand = self.random_state.rand(self.n_components, self.n_symbols)
emissionprob = preprocessing.normalize(rand, norm='l1', axis=1, copy=False)
```